# How to call the destructor of a C++ class from within python

Tags: python, c++, boost, memory-leaks

I suspect that I have a memory leak problem.

I expose a C++ class (**A**) to python using boost. This class has a member which is a pointer to another class (**B**)  which uses a lot of memory. I have a proper destructor in class A which takes care of freeing up the memory.

My problem is that when I expose class A to python (**P_A**) and create several instances of P_A in a **loop** the used memory seems to be the sum of all different P_A's memory. I need each P_A object only once in a loop, ideally I would manually call the destructor of the underlying C++  class (P) in each step in the loop. Is this possible or are there other approaches to deal with this problem? I am not sure how reference counting works in this case, but I would guess that once a new python object of type P_A is reassigned to the same variable name (in the loop), the previous object should be deallocated and somehow call the underlying C++ destructor. Is this always the case? (if yes, then I cannot explain the memory problem I observe). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using CPython or some other Python implementation?

Comment: I use this: Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 25 2014, 13:52:19) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1)] on linux2

Comment: Have you put trace code in your destructor to verify it is being called? How are you determining memory usage?

Comment: No, this is actually a good idea, I'll put a cout in the destructor. Regarding memory usage, I see it with the top command or the System Monitor GUI in Fedora. I am sure that it is the python process which I am running (if I kill it the used memory disappears)

Comment: I don't think that's a reliable way of checking for memory leaks. Memory may not be returned to the OS even if it is freed properly, but retained for future use by the program.

Comment: but is there any way to force to free up this memory, e.g. calling the destructor manually?

Comment: Calling a destructor won't free any memory anyway.

Comment: @FredLarson: yes, the destructor is called in python

Comment: If your destructor is being called and is correctly freeing memory, you should be fine. You might be able to use valgrind to detect leaks.

Comment: @steve: it will if the destructor is coded to free memory, as the OP has indicated: "I have a proper destructor in class A *which takes care of freeing up the memory.*"

Comment: @FredLarson But the memory used by the object itself won't be freed, just the memory dynamically allocated by that object.

Comment: @Steve: Boost.Python should handle that just fine. If it's allocating the memory, it'll clean it up.

Comment: Thanks to the commenters, I think the problem was that I needed a new build. Since the source code (C++ bindings) did not change make did not recompile. Some external .so lib changed however (which was used by the C++ code in class B). I do not have any other logical explanation but all seems to work now.